# Pandas: Using datetime as a condition

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I'm using a for loop to plot all of the features in my dataset. I want it to skip plotting any attributes that have a datetime type. It doesn't seem to skipping correctly.....what do I need to fix?

(JFYI, I have confirmed with df.dtypes that the columns appear as datetime64[ns])

```
def plot_distribution(dataset, cols=5, width=20, height=50, hspace=0.2, wspace=0.5):
    plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width,height))
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=wspace, hspace=hspace)
    rows = math.ceil(float(dataset.shape[1]) / cols)
    for i, column in enumerate(dataset.columns):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(rows, cols, i + 1)
        ax.set_title(column)
        g = sns.countplot(y=column, hue = target_column, data = df)
        if df.dtypes[column] == np.datetime64:
                continue



plot_distribution(df, cols=1, width=20, height=500, hspace=0.8, wspace=0.5)
```

Comment: are you certain that `df.dtypes` contains an np.datetime64 column?

Comment: for a dataframe, datetime is most likely be string `'datetime64[ns]'` or the like.

Comment: @QuangHoang when I try "if df.dtypes[column] == np.datetime64[ns]:" it returns the error "np is not defined". It excludes the brackets from the datatype.

Comment: `np is not defined`: did you import `np`? also, it's plain string 'datetime64[ns]`, not an `np` type. Try to print `df.dtypes[column]` first.